# Changing employer with later issued date Blue Card

Tags: germany, blue-card, employment

I graduated from TUM in Informatiks in February 2020 and got a full-time job offer from the same company I was working as a student. I started the full-time job in March and applied for my Blue Card at the KVR. I got the appointment for 28.05.2020, but due to the pandemic, the appointment got canceled. It was only in November when I got another appointment, hence the issue date on my Blue Card is 13.11.2020.

Now I have a new job offer, I've already signed the contract and my job starts on 24.10.2022, and 21.10.2022 is my last day at my current company. I was wondering if I need to ask the KVR for permission to change employers since it's not been 2 years since the issue date of my Blue Card, but in fact, I have been a full-time employee for more than 30 months. What is the ideal course of action here? I've been living in Germany for ~6 years and employed for the whole time (Werkstudent or Vollzeit) if that matters. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: hey any updates on your situation?